# multiple string split javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an application that injects one query in a record field in a database .
at the moment I need to take a string that contains a query and divide by commas

This is the string

```
APDoc.brn, APDoc.rbtn, APDoc.perd, APDoc.dtip, APDoc.U5, APDoc.Stt, APDoc.Ivcn, APDoc.InvcD, APDoc.Vndd AS Rut, Venr.ae AS Proveedor, APDoc.At, CASE APDoc.Dcype WHEN 'AD' THEN APDoc.OgDocmt * -1  WHEN 'PP' THEN APDoc.OrocAmt * -1 ELSE APDoc.OrocAmt END AS [Monto Fac], APDoc.POr, APDoc.Sb AS Entidad, APDoc.ProjeD, CASE APDoc.Dype WHEN 'AD' THEN APDoc.Dal * -1 WHEN 'PP' THEN APDoc.Dal * -1 ELSE APDoc.Dal END AS Saldo,  datediff(day, APDoc.Inate, GETDATE()) AS DIFERENCIA_DIAS
```

basically had no problems by separating them with a split () and join ()

```
queryCortada      = queryCortada.split("AND").join(",").split("OR").join(",").split("(").join("").split(")").join("").split(",");
```

the problem is that the last field separates it into the following

```
datediff(day,
APDoc.Inate,
GETDATE()) AS DIFERENCIA_DIAS
```

I need this field being only one,  the idea is to have the following

```
APDoc.brn,
APDoc.rbtn,
APDoc.perd,
APDoc.dtip,
APDoc.U5,
APDoc.Stt,
APDoc.Ivcn,
APDoc.InvcD,
APDoc.Vndd AS Rut,
Venr.ae AS Proveedor,
APDoc.At,
CASE APDoc.Dcype WHEN 'AD' THEN APDoc.OgDocmt * -1  WHEN 'PP' THEN APDoc.OrocAmt * -1 ELSE APDoc.OrocAmt END AS [Monto Fac],
APDoc.POr, APDoc.Sb AS Entidad,
APDoc.ProjeD, CASE APDoc.Dype WHEN 'AD' THEN APDoc.Dal * -1 WHEN 'PP' THEN APDoc.Dal * -1 ELSE APDoc.Dal END AS Saldo,
datediff(day, APDoc.Inate, GETDATE()) AS DIFERENCIA_DIAS
```

The original text could contain more than one field as datediff( asdas,asdasd,asdasd)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you either need to write a complex regex or parse the string through a lexical state-machine.

A simple split will always cause issues with future statements even if you think you covered your bases today.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
queryCortada.replace(/\((.*)\)+/g, "(temp**comma)").split("AND").join(",").split("OR").join(",").split("(").join("").split(")").join("").replace(/temp\*\*comma/g, ",").split(",");
```